# Visual Studio: Match Regex Across Varying Number of Newlines

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace, newline

Given the following HTML:

```
<tag1>
    <tag2 attr2="val2"/>
</tag1>
<tag1>
    <tag2
    attr2="val2"/>
</tag1>
```

I want to wipe out all tag2's in that HTML with one regex in Visual Studio.

To match the first:
`\<tag2.+\/\>`

To match the second:
`\<tag2.*\n.*\/\>`

So suppose I want to merge these 2 strategies to match both. None of the below match both tag2 tags:

```
\<tag2.*\/\>
\<tag2[.\n]*\/\>
\<tag2.*\n?.*\/\>
\<tag2[.\r\n]*\/\>
```

I get:
First tag
No match
No match
No match

They really ought to, but it seems as though the variable number of newlines causes VS to never match. Bug?

This plagues me in VS2005, VS2008, and VS2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` should be outside the `[]`, otherwise it matches only a single literal `.` character. Try:

```
\<tag2(.|[\r\n])*\/\>
```

Comment: Great lead - that actually matches too much. In HTML with multiple tags that end in \> in a row, it matches all of them at once, rather than one at a time. However, that leads to this, which DOES work! Thanks! \<tag2([^\>]|\n)*\/\>